# Solr - HTTP Status 403 - не могу зайти в админку Solr

Tags: solr, tomcat

Всем привет. На сервере с Ubuntu Server 10.04 работает некоторое веб-приложение, использующее Solr. Ранее использовался Tomcat 6. После перехода на Tomcat 7 перестал пускать по http://my-site:3080/solr/.

При попытке зайти выдает:

```
HTTP Status 403 - 
type   Status report
message   
description   Access to the specified resource () has been forbidden.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
```

Перерыл все конфиги, все пути пересмотрел. Проверил еще раз права доступа, веб-приложение перенастроил, но ничего... Какой-то ступор. К сожалению, с Java я дружу плохо, поэтому буду рад любым советам. Подскажите, хотя бы в каком направлении искать решение проблемы?

Comment: Мда, чувствую, проблема нерешаемая. :))) Есть у кого-нибудь хотя бы предположения, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Проблема была в некорректно указанном диапазоне IP-адресов, с которых разрешен доступ к solr в конфиге solr.xml. У меня он находится в /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml. К сожалению, не знаю, какой должен быть правильный формат диапазона IP-адресов, но где-то читал, что он должен соответствовать регулярному выражению. Если не прав, поправьте, пожалуйста, в комментах. Не было времени с этим разбираться. Я просто указал один IP-адрес, с которого пытался зайти в админку. В моем случае этого было достаточно. Правда, к еще большему сожалению, теперь получаю ошибку 500. Но данная проблема ре